# In R, is it possible to save the current workspace without quitting?

Tags: r

I want to save an image of the workspace in the .RData file but without exiting the current session. Something like `q('yes')` but without quitting.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `save.image()` at any time to save all environment data into an `.RData` file:

```
save.image(file='yoursession.RData')
```

To load this data later you can use:

```
load('yoursession.RData')
```

Comment: `save.image` saves the objects. But, unfortunately, if the user closes R session by closing R GUI, then when the next time user loads the `.Rdata` file, the loaded packages in previous session _must_ be re-loaded once again since they are removed from the Loaded Packages list in the Object Browser. The user specifies "without Quiting". I wonder  if there is a way to re-get both _objects_ and _loaded packages_ for the next R session.

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER The user can always update his `.Rprofile` file to have the required packages.  But I see your point in the event that the user had loaded _new_ packages during the session whose objects were just saved.

Comment: Thx a lot. Inspired from [link](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html), I noticed that the `Rprofile.site` file is here: `C:\Revolution\R-Enterprise-7.3\R-3.1.1\etc` for Revolution R Enterprise GUI. Then, I added one more package (`causfinder`) in `Rprofile.site` file in `options(defaultPackages=c(getOption("defaultPackages"), "rpart", "lattice", "RevoScaleR", "RevoMods", "Revobase", "causfinder"))` then the next R session was started with the added package. This is great usage: Considering, e.g. for VAR analyzers, `vars`, `urca`, `tsDyn` can be added there.

Comment: does the extension of the file matter ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas You may try it and find out.  To my knowledge, no, the extension/filename can be whatever you want (even no extension).

Answer (score 3):

Apart from `save.image()` function, that lets you save the entire workspace, you can also check the `save()` function.

`save()` function lets you save **individual objects** in the workspace.

```
 save(ObjectToBeSaved, file = "FileName.RData")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `session` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/session/versions/1.0.3 package allows to save/load both objects and also loaded packages. Although it was removed from CRAN some time ago, it is still functional (R v4.1) and can be installed from the archive easily

```
 install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/session/session_1.0.3.tar.gz")
```

To use it, do

```
session::save.session(".mysession.dat")

session::restore.session(".mysession.dat")
```

This often works much better `save.image` because, without packages, the session information tends to be too incomplete to be useful.